# How to make CKEditor image responsive in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I m using gem `'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'` with rails admin.
I want when I post article on the homepage, images associated with article's description should be automatic responsive. I have one folder in

> assets/Javascript/ckeditor

, and I posted this  [piece of code](https://gist.github.com/fabiomaggio/c2f4b84756cb4d82c0ae) in this folder, but it seems not working too. please help me out. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want inserted images in a CKEditor to be responsive you can use the following code. It creates a htmlfilter for the
>   image tag that replaces inline "width" and "style" definitions with
>   their corresponding attributes and add's (in this example) the
>   **Bootstrap "img-responsive" class**.

I believe CKEDITOR does not add the `img-responsive` class to those images. You can check this by adding an image with `CKEDITOR` and then check if the html on the page has the `img-responsive` class added.

The function `CKEDITOR.on()` the event `'instanceReady'` will execute the code to add the `'img-responsive'` class to the image element `el`

The fact is, I believe you should put a breakpoint inside that code and test if it is actually executing

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) { // etc.. etc.. });
```

because [this are the instruction on how to adapt ckeditor with turbolinks](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#turbolink-integration)

> Create a file app/assets/javascripts/init_ckeditor.coffee

```
var ready = function() {
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) { // code });
}

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

> Make sure the file is loaded from your app/assets/javascripts/application.js

[`CKEDITOR` is the **API entry point**. The entire CKEditor code runs under this object.](https://docs.ckeditor.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/api/CKEDITOR)

[The documentation of the `.on()` jquery method](https://api.jquery.com/on/) can help you understand better why that call is not executing, basically the `.on()` method trigger the js code in the `function(){}`, when that event is triggered.

The event is `instanceReady` and this is the [info from the API](https://docs.ckeditor.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/api/CKEDITOR#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceReady)

> instanceReady( evt )
>   Event fired when a CKEDITOR instance is created, fully initialized and ready for interaction.

```
Parameters
evt : CKEDITOR.eventInfo
editor : CKEDITOR.editor
The editor instance that has been created.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

Add this in your CSS file:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

### Method 2

Use [Enhanced Image](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/image2) plugin to replace the default image widget.

### Method 3

Use the [snippet](https://gist.github.com/fabiomaggio/c2f4b84756cb4d82c0ae) in your link, but remember to replace the `img-responsvie` to `img-fluid` if you use Bootstrap 4.